# How to separate numbers from string and the number should appear separately in separate cells in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, formula, spreadsheet

I have a data in "A" column like as below starting from A2 cell.

7cz2
6789efg
abc890
34l1
78kk
88
63

What I need is
7
2
6
7
8
9
8
9
0
3
4
7
8
8
8
6
3.

I do have applied **=VALUE(REGEXREPLACE(A2,"\D+", ""))** but is is giving me data like

72
6789
890
34
78.

Is there a way to solve this.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use 2 formulas.

1. join and replace letters in cell C1:

`=REGEXREPLACE(JOIN("",A1:A7),"[A-Za-z]","")`

2. split by symbol:

`=TRANSPOSE(REGEXEXTRACT(C1,REPT("(.)",LEN(C1))))`

The result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, Max. Your support really helped me. :)